# Analyze traditional triangle-type mesh by voxels

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d, openvdb

I have a [qmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake) project on Qt Creator using [Qt3D](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html) to render 3D scenes with [triangle-type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qgeometryrenderer.html#PrimitiveType-enum) meshes. An example is available [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-simple-cpp-example.html). I intend to use OpenVDB [tools](https://www.openvdb.org/about/) to analyze my Qt3D meshes.

- Is converting Qt3D meshes to  OpenVDB grid the right approach to be able to use OpenVDB tools by Qt3D?
- What is the best approach to analyze my Qt3D meshes by OpenVDB grid tools?
- Is there any any documentation or reference material which might help?

There is [Qt3DOpenVDBRenderer](https://github.com/MASKOR/Qt3DOpenVDBRenderer) repository, but:

- As far as I understand, it just loads OpenVDB grids and renders them with Qt3D
- It doesn't deal with existing Qt3D meshes
- It only considers `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Points` as [primitive type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qgeometryrenderer.html#PrimitiveType-enum) but I need `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Triangles`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of [`VoxelizePolygons`](https://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/classopenvdb_1_1v6__2_1_1tools_1_1mesh__to__volume__internal_1_1VoxelizePolygons.html)?